# Mocking multiple react custom hooks with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I have a custom React hook that makes a async api call and returns the response.
The implementation is as follows:

```js
  const {
    response,
    call,
    loading,
  } = useAsyncRequest({
    args: [collection, uid, schema],
    callFn: apiGetDocument,
  });
```

I can then mock this component easily with jest like below:

```js
AsyncRequestManager
      .mockReturnValue(defaultAsyncHookReturnLoad)
```

This works if I only use one of these hooks but if I used multiple (i.e. 1 for loading and 1 for saving) then I have to mock both responses separately as below:

```js
AsyncRequestManager
      .mockReturnValueOnce(defaultAsyncHookReturnLoad)
      .mockReturnValueOnce(defaultAsyncHookReturnSave);
```

Which works for the same render but not for following rerenders.

Is it possible to tell jest to return in a value in sequence?

i.e something like the below (Which does not work because of scoped variables)

```js
let i = 0;
AsyncRequestManager.mockImplementation(() => {
    i += 1;
    if (i % 3 === 0) return defaultAsyncHookReturnLoad;
    if (i % 3 === 1) return defaultAsyncHookReturnSave;
    if (i % 3 === 2) return defaultAsyncHookReturnDelete
    // i += 1;
});
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Adam's comment the above solution seems to  work. Hurrah!

Comment: Why doesn't `mockImplementation` work? More importantly, the arguments the implementation is called with are available as the arguments in `mockImplementation` and they can be used to determine what return value you want to use.

Comment: `let i` is outside the mock implementation scope so it is not updated within the mock implementation

Comment: That’s because i+=1 is never executed because it’s after the return statements.

Comment: Ha feeling pretty stupid now but that did the trick thanks!

Comment: just to clarify, the solution as written leads to brittle tests - it depends on an implementation detail - the fact you use 3 hooks in that order. If you change the implementation but not the result, the test fails. It’s far better to use the arguments to mockImplementation to determine what mock return value to use, rather than the order in which they are called.